# Cup product of $H^{\bullet}(\mathbb{R}P^{2};\,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ in terms of cellular cohomology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

Considering the CW complex structure on $\mathbb{R}P^{2}$ consisting of one $0$-cell, one $1$-cell and one $2$-cell. Then the cellular chain complex of $\mathbb{R}P^{2}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2$-coefficient is given by
$$\mathbb{Z}/2\cdot e^{2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\cdot e^{1} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\cdot e^{0}$$
where $e^{i}$ denotes the $i$-cell and all differentials are zero.

Applying the functor $\mathrm{Hom}(-,\,\mathbb{Z}/2)$, we can get the cellular cochain complex of $\mathbb{R}P^{2}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2$-coefficient:
$$\mathbb{Z}/2\cdot \epsilon ^{2} \longleftarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\cdot \epsilon ^{1} \longleftarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\cdot \epsilon ^{0}$$
where $\epsilon^{i}$ can be thought as the function sending $e^{i}$ to $1$.

Since differentials are all zero, the cellular cohomology of $\mathbb{R}P^{2}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2$-coefficient is also generated by $\epsilon^{i}$'s.

My question is what is the cup product $\epsilon ^{1}\cup \epsilon ^{1}\in H^{2}(\mathbb{R}P^{2};\,\mathbb{Z}/2)$? It could be $0$ or $\epsilon ^{2}$.

The cup product can be viewed as the composition of 
$$H^{1}(\mathbb{R}P^{2};\,\mathbb{Z}/2)\otimes H^{1}(\mathbb{R}P^{2};\,\mathbb{Z}/2) \longrightarrow H^{2}(\mathbb{R}P^{2}\times \mathbb{R}P^{2};\,\mathbb{Z}/2)\longrightarrow H^{2}(\mathbb{R}P^{2};\,\mathbb{Z}/2)$$

The first map sends $\epsilon^{1}\otimes\epsilon^{1}$ to the 2-cochain on $\mathbb{R}P^{2}\times \mathbb{R}P^{2}$ that takes value $1$ on $e^{1}\times e^{1}$ and $0$ on $e^{2}\times e^{0}$ and $e^{0}\times e^{2}$.

The second map is dual to the cellular approximation of the diagonal map $$\Delta:\,\mathbb{R}P^{2}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}P^{2}\times \mathbb{R}P^{2}$$
However, I don't understand this map. If it sends $e^{2}$ to $e^{1}\times e^{1}$, then we have $\epsilon ^{1}\cup \epsilon ^{1}=\epsilon^{2}$, otherwise we will have $\epsilon ^{1}\cup \epsilon ^{1}=0$.

I really appreciate if someone can give me some explanations on this cup product via cellular cochains or some geometry behind this product.

Comment: Well, we should have $\epsilon^1 \cup \epsilon^1 = \epsilon^2$, the cohomology ring with mod 2 coefficients is $ \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3) $